# How to deserialize from JSON to LocalDate, while also using JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS?

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have enabled *jackson-datatype-joda*, but it's not working with the `JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS`.

I have set up ObjectMapper as following:

```
ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
jacksonObjectMapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS, true);
jacksonObjectMapper.registerModule(new JodaModule());
```

When deserializing (using *com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.LocalDateDeserializer*), I end up with the error:

```
org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Current token (VALUE_STRING) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors
at [...]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Current token (VALUE_STRING) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors
```

I've debugged the *LocalDateDeserializer* and found out, that it's expecting *VALUE_NUMBER_INT* - while the `JsonGenerator.Feature.WRITE_NUMBERS_AS_STRINGS` makes the date having Strings.

When I've turned off that Feature, everything was all right.

Is there any possibility that this feature (or similar) will work with Joda Time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Joda` module uses [`com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.joda.deser.LocalDateDeserializer`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-joda/2.4.0-rc2/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/joda/deser/LocalDateDeserializer.java?av=f) for deserializing `org.joda.time.LocalDate` objects. This class looks like this:

```
@Override
public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
{
    // [yyyy,mm,dd]
    if (jp.isExpectedStartArrayToken()) {
        jp.nextToken(); // VALUE_NUMBER_INT 
        int year = jp.getIntValue(); 
        jp.nextToken(); // VALUE_NUMBER_INT
        int month = jp.getIntValue();
        jp.nextToken(); // VALUE_NUMBER_INT
        int day = jp.getIntValue();
        if (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
            throw ctxt.wrongTokenException(jp, JsonToken.END_ARRAY, "after LocalDate ints");
        }
        return new LocalDate(year, month, day);
    }
    switch (jp.getCurrentToken()) {
    case VALUE_NUMBER_INT:
        return new LocalDate(jp.getLongValue());            
    case VALUE_STRING:
        String str = jp.getText().trim();
        if (str.length() == 0) { // [JACKSON-360]
            return null;
        }
        return parser.parseLocalDate(str);
    default:
    }
    throw ctxt.wrongTokenException(jp, JsonToken.START_ARRAY, "expected JSON Array, String or Number");
}
```

As you can see, if `LocalDate` is array this deserializer expects ints in this array. You can write your custom deserializer and extend this implementation. See below example:

```
class LocalDateWithStringsDeserializer extends LocalDateDeserializer {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public LocalDate deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException,
            JsonProcessingException {
        // [yyyy,mm,dd] or ["yyyy","mm","dd"]
        if (jp.isExpectedStartArrayToken()) {
            return parseArray(jp, ctxt);
        }

        return super.deserialize(jp, ctxt);
    }

    private LocalDate parseArray(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt)
            throws JsonParseException, IOException {
        int year = getNextValue(jp);
        int month = getNextValue(jp);
        int day = getNextValue(jp);
        if (jp.nextToken() != JsonToken.END_ARRAY) {
            throw ctxt.wrongTokenException(jp, JsonToken.END_ARRAY, "after LocalDate ints");
        }
        return new LocalDate(year, month, day);
    }

    private int getNextValue(JsonParser jp) throws IOException, JsonParseException {
        jp.nextToken();

        return new Integer(jp.getText());
    }
}
```

Now you can link above deserializer and your property:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = LocalDateWithStringsDeserializer.class)
private LocalDate date;
```

Comment: That would be great to include your solution into the Jackson's _LocalDateDeserializer_. Will it be possible?

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea. I will create pull request to this project on GitHub: https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time

Comment: Hi again. Almost after a year I finally have created pull request which was accepted. This bug was fixed and will be available in next release. See this link: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-joda/pull/62#event-315186515